# the function called from contract by web3 isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, solidity, web3js

I'm doing the contract and wanna connect to the js and html by web3. When I try doing the function **saveData** in the contract **save.sol**, the ganache network didn't create the new block, but it should do.

why the `contract.methods.saveData(date, resource, mycalculate, material)` in index.js didn't work?

the version of web3 is 1.5.1

the codes are shown in the following

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
ignored

          <div style="text-align: center;">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="button_formCarbonEmission">Save</button>
            <a href="./home.html" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a>
          </div>

          <script>
            const form = document.querySelector('form')
            const submitButton = document.querySelector('#button_formCarbonEmission')
      
            submitButton.addEventListener('click', function onSubmitButtonClicked(event){
              form.classList.add('was-validated')
            })
      
            form.addEventListener('submit', function onFormSubmit(event){
              if(!form.checkValidity()){
                event.preventDefault()
                event.stopPropagation()
              }
            })
          </script>

        </form>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
    <script src="../function/web3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../function/index.js"></script>
    ignored    
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
// Initialize Web3
var web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:7545');

// Set Account
web3.eth.defaultAccount = '0x16E15b184F39c4fBE1A4B29052CE018c5748610B';

// Set Contract Abi
var ABI = [myabi];

// Set Contract Address
var contractAddress = 'myaddr'; // Add Your Contract address here!!!

// Set the Contract
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, contractAddress);

// get the current time 
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-' + (today.getMonth()+1) + '-' + today.getDate() + '-'
today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds;


//get the formCarbonEmission data
const submitBtn = document.getElementById("button_formCarbonEmission");
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', processFormData);

contract.methods.test().call().then(console.log);//work normally

function processFormData() {
  const form = document.forms['formCarbonEmission'];
  const material = form.elements.material.value;
  const resource = form.elements.resource.value;
  const mycalculate = form.elements.mycalculate.value;

    //save the data
  contract.methods.saveData(date, resource, mycalculate, material).call(); **//this function isn't work**

    //alert
    alert("saved!");
}
```

save.sol:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Storage{

    string b = "calculation a";
    struct UserInfo {
        string time;
        string source;
        uint emission;
    }
    mapping (string => UserInfo) users;
    
    function test() public view returns(string memory) {
        return b;
    }

    function saveData(string memory input_time, string memory input_source, string memory input_mycalculate, uint input_material) public {
        users[input_source].time = input_time;
        if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(input_mycalculate)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(b)))
            users[input_source].emission = input_material * 3 / 2;//solidity isn't support integer
        else
            users[input_source].emission = input_material * 5 / 2;//solidity isn't support integer
    }
    
/*     function get() public view returns (string memory, uint, string memory) {
        return (source, emission, time);
    } */ 
    
    function search(string memory input_source) public view returns (uint, string memory) {
        return (users[input_source].emission, users[input_source].time);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by creating the file "web3.js" and injected the file to the index.js

and added the account of savedata:

```
contract.methods.saveData(date, resource, mycalculate, material).send(
        {from:web3.eth.defaultAccount}
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

`contract.methods.saveData(date, resource, mycalculate, material)` has to be called with:

- `call(params)` - read/simulate operation
- `send(params)` - write operation

As you saw, your `call()` haven't worked as you didn't provide any parameters but `send(params)` did work.